# Can you have an async functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you do async functional components like:

```
const MyComponent = async ({ children }) => {return null}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

Comment: the question is why do you want a asynchronous functional component ? ,From my understanding having an async component would take it out of the main render loop

Comment: A function component (or a render method in a class component) cannot return a promise. What are you attempting to do this for? There is likely a different way to accomplish your goal

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not. You could kind of achieve the same result with a helper like this:

```
function makeAsyncComponent(fn) {
  return React.useMemo(function Component(props) {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
       fn().then(result => setResult(result))
    });

    return result;
  });
}

const MyComponent = makeAsyncComponent(async ({ children }) => {return null})
```